# Grid system needed to fix a position issue on canvas?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple snake game. My problem is, most of the times when the snake meets the food, the position of the snake is not how it should be.

For a better understanding, please look at this screenshot where the snake (white) meets the food (green):

[image]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    x = 0,
    y = 0, 
    speed = 3; 
    x_move = speed,
    y_move = 0,
    food_position_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width) - 20;
    food_position_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height) - 20;

// Drawing
function draw() { 
  requestAnimationFrame(function() { 
    draw();
  });
  // Draw the snake
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, 20, 20);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; 
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  // Draw the food
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(food_position_x, food_position_y, 20, 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightgreen";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  // Increase the value of x and y in order to animate
  x = x + x_move;
  y = y + y_move;
} 
draw();

// Key Pressing
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  switch(event.keyCode) {
    case 40: // Moving down
      if (x_move != 0 && y_move != -1) {
        x_move = 0;
        y_move = speed;
      }
    break;
    case 39: // Moving right
      if (x_move != -1 && y_move != 0) {
        x_move = speed;
        y_move = 0; 
      }
    break;
    case 38: // Moving top
      if (x_move != 0 && y_move != 1) {
        x_move = 0;
        y_move = -speed; 
      }
    break;
    case 37: // Moving left
      if (x_move != 1 && y_move != 0) {
        x_move = -speed;
        y_move = 0; 
      }
    break;
  }
});
```

```css
canvas { background-color:red }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

So it seems like I would need a simple grid system but how would I go ahead on this to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the code for your collision. But I think you have a mistake in your origin. The origin of your squares is not in the middle, it is on the top left corner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I set the origin of the squares?

Comment: Do you still need help? I can detailed look for the problem tomorrow.

Comment: It works when I use `ctx.rect(Math.floor(x/10)*10, Math.floor(y/10)*10, 10, 10);` for drawing the snake and `ctx.rect(Math.floor(food_position_x/10)*10, Math.floor(food_position_y/10)*10, 10, 10);` for drawing the food but I have no idea why.

Comment: I think, that's wrong. You only make the last number to zero.
For example x => 117 will become 110. I think you have to substract the half of the width and height, to put the origin in the center of your rectangle:
food_position_x - width/2, food_position_y - heigth/2, width, height
And the same for the snake.